# llvm dumping control flow graph to file inside a pass

Tags: llvm, control-flow-graph, llvm-3.1

I want to build a control flow graph diagram in llvm in one of my passes. I currently use the following to show the CFG

```
block->getParent()->viewCFG(); //block is a basic block
```

The problem is that it pops up a windows. I just want to dump the cfg at that particular program point, as a dot file (or jpg if possible), not to show up in a window. How can I do the same? I am using llvm 3.1.

**NOTE:** I am modifying the cfg in my pass, before that program point. Hence I cannot use the `opt -view-cfg`.

**Update:**

Thanks to Mishr, I was able to draw to graph with this

`WriteGraph(File, (const llvm::Function*) &fun, true, "test"); //I have also tired with false`

The CFG is shown. But the nodes are blank. How can I show the contents of the node

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this, read the comment before the `viewCFG()` function.

http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/CFGPrinter_8cpp_source.html

The `viewCFG()` function is intended for printing the CFG in a new window. To dump the CFG in a file you have to use `CFGPrinter` pass which can be invoked by the handle `dot-cfg`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Could please give a reference on how to use it. I cant find a function in that class for doing the same

Comment: `CFGPrinter` is a pass, you can use it via `opt`.

Comment: But how do I specify at which program point should it draw the graph? it would be great if you could point to some sample usage

Comment: You could introduce your own function in the CFGPrinter.cpp which performs the same thing as the `dot-cfg` pass is doing, and then call it as you were calling `viewCFG`.

Comment: BTW what purpose will it serve to print CFG while the pass is still working on IR? If it is at the end of the pass then why not emit IR, and then use `opt` to get the CFG?

Comment: Thankyou for the reply. I will check this out. I hope you dont have a sample. I have upvoted the post. The reason why I need this is that, in various stages of my pass, I am modifying my control flow graph. In different regions of the pass, the same basic block may be modified, cloned etc. So for debugging and logging I need to dump the control flow at various points. This is why I cant generate the control flow graph before or after my pass. I really need it inside the pass itself

Answer (score 2):

Let me add something to ssubbotin's answer.
The question is about

```
DOTGraphTraits<const Function*>
```

provided by CFGPrinter.

In my case I had to use the call like that:

```
WriteGraph<const llvm::Function*>(...)
```

to make it work.

The function template definition is like the following:

```
template<typename GraphType>
raw_ostream &WriteGraph(raw_ostream &O, const GraphType &G,
                        bool ShortNames = false,
                        const Twine &Title = "")
```

so GraphType gets non-const with implicit template call.

Comment: It's best to add this as a comment to the relevant answer, rather than making it an answer by itself.

Comment: yeah, unfortunately I don't have enough rank for that :\

Answer (score 1):

You need to add include:
`#include <llvm\Analysis\CFGPrinter.h>`

It has getEdgeSourceLabel implementation inside which provides correct node labels.
In the same time, make sure you **don't** have `<llvm\Support\CFG.h>` file included since it provides empty labels by default.